# Where .net maui app creates log files? From where and how we can access it?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, maui

I have noticed that we do not have access to logging in Maui and need a solution to be able to get to logs within our Maui app.

So here what I'm looking is from where we can access the log files in .Net Maui apps?

I have tried to print the path of log file but that did not helped me. So,want to know by default where maui stores the log files for Android & iOS?

Comment: Maui doesn't manage this; each platform (Android; iOS) has its own mechanism. google `android log files`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe MAUI does not log any logs. You can add your log using .NET tools. There is also a video of Gerald versus the logs:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WicmnH72kf0&t=851s

https://github.com/roubachof/MetroLog

Comment: How to get log file location using MetroLog?